# ERC20 in game token restrict

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have created a game where user can claim tokens they earned.

My questions is:

How to restrict to directly mint from the token contract, and use only claim function within the game ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. In the contract, create a role that will only be allowed to claim tokens. You can use OpenZeppelin's Roles (`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";`).
2. Use the backend function that will be called from the game to call claim with the address of the allowed role (see step 1) to create tokens for the player. In the same function before creating tokens make all necessary checks on the authorized player

Comment: Sounds good, but if i set a certain role to mint the tokens because here claim tokens = mint function.  How do I transfer then from this (role) address to the address that specifically played ? Manually ?

Comment: You will need to call a function (or other contract) on the back end that will call the claim from its address (the address of the authorized role)